# Image Gallery Has Blurry Images

Tags: media, javascript

My image gallery is showing the images blurry. Its using Ligthbox2. When I click on the images, they show clear in the lightbox. Is this a lightbox setting?

Answer (score 0):

Setting my lightbox setting to Display: Single lightbox: large => large fixed the problem. thanks. :)